# How to store n-highest values and how to ignore words less than a min length?

Tags: java, string, max

Assume we have the following function which finds the highest frequent word of a passage:

```
private static String countKeyword(File from) throws IOException {
    final Path path = Paths.get(from.getPath());
    final Map<String, Integer> counts = countOccurrences(path);

    Map.Entry<String, Integer> maxEntry = null;

    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : counts.entrySet())
    {
        if (maxEntry == null || entry.getValue().compareTo(maxEntry.getValue()) > 0)
        {
            maxEntry = entry;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(maxEntry.getKey());
    return maxEntry.getKey();   
}

private static Map<String, Integer> countOccurrences(Path path) throws IOException {
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[gG][a-bA-B].+",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

    try (final Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path))
    {
        return lines
            .flatMap(pattern::splitAsStream)
            .collect(toMap(identity(), w -> 1, Integer::sum));
    }
}
```

Now how can we change this to another function which returns the n-highest frequent words? And how can we change the `countOccurrences(Path path)` so it ignores words less than a min length?

Comment: I would appreciate some comment when there is a down vote.

Comment: Well, this question is kind of like providing `1 + 1 = 2` and then asking how to do multiplication. You didn't attempt anything yourself. Secondly, you wrote 2 questions instead of one.

Comment: You could easily separate the two questions. We don't even need to see `countOccurrences` for answering the first one.

Comment: @Manu Then how are you going to know the way I count the occurrence of words?

Comment: That is irrelevant for the first question...

Comment: @Manu It is,. You might just change the storing occurrences in a way that it sorts all words and then we just get the last n-highest ones in the sorted array/list etc.

Comment: @Manu I meant it is not*